# Get all rows where a value is in at least one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which is taking quite a long time, and I am trying to improve the performance. It looks at a linkage table, and finds the advisor links (which could be either the start or end contact). For the purpose of this example, I am just doing one contact (468), it will actually be running for 100s of them.

```
(select c2.first_name
 from crm_contact c2
 where (
                   c2.id = (
                   select cl.start_contact_entity
                   from crm_contact_linkages cl
                   where 468 != c2.id
                     and cl.effective_to is null
                     and cl.relationship = 'ADVISOR'
                     and (cl.start_contact_entity = 468 or cl.ending_contact_entity = 468)
                   limit 1
               ) or
                   c2.id = (
                       select cl.ending_contact_entity
                       from crm_contact_linkages cl
                       where 468 != c2.id
                         and cl.effective_to is null
                         and cl.relationship = 'ADVISOR'
                         and (cl.start_contact_entity = 468 or cl.ending_contact_entity = 468)
                       limit 1
                   )
           )
 LIMIT 1)
```

Obviosuly I am doing the same query twice inside, one checking for the start and one checking for the end. I thought there would be a way to run that subquery once, get the start and end, and then check the c2.id off that, but I am unable to find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want the code to do would really help.  Your code is also comparing one value (`id`) to a subquery returning two values.  I would expect this to return an error.  Further, `limit` without an `order by` is highly suspicious.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I would expect the c2.id to filter based on the start OR end contact fields. I am not comparing the id to a subquery returning two values, there are two separate uses of "c2.id = ". Apologies I've updated the original question. The limit was just for a purpose of testing, but we can assume for the purpose of this there is only one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry I had pasted the wrong thing, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can rewrite this to a single EXISTS condition:

```
select c2.first_name
from crm_contact c2
where c2.id <> 468 
  and exists (
    select *
    from crm_contact_linkages cl
    where cl.effective_to is null
      and cl.relationship = 'ADVISOR'
      and (cl.start_contact_entity = 468 or cl.ending_contact_entity = 468)
      and c2.id in (cl.start_contact_entity, cl.ending_contact_entity))
```

The `c2.id <> 468` seems more appropriate in the outer query, not in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=25c2f896ac85d1a7ae16ad4048554d28)

```
... 
WHERE c2.id = ANY(
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY[cl.start_contact_entity, cl.ending_contact_entity])
    FROM ...
)
```

Put your both columns into an array and unnest it, to create one column which contains both, start and ending value.